# Linux loses value after mysqli_stmt_close

Tags: php, linux, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've coded this PHP in my Windows and works fine, but on linux it loses the value.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT name from `table` where ID=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"i",$id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $name);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
if (is_null($name))
 echo 'Empty';
```

On Linux it always shows empty but if i change the code to

...

```
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
if (is_null($name))
 echo 'Empty';
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

then it does not show `EMPTY`

I've used $id with a value which exist in table.

tested on

PHP 5.2
Suse Linux

I use PHP 5.3.3  on XP

Comment: Sorry, maby I missed something, but what exactly is $flag? And why don't you use var_dump for debugging?

Comment: I've used xdebug, it does not show anything wrong, i've also set error_reporting to display all error, it also does not show any error !

Comment: I have Ubuntu 11.04 with latest updates (can specify php/mysql/etc. versions if you need) and I still have $name avaliable after mysqli_stmt_close() (Just tested).

Comment: what mysql u have ? i got 5.2 on server

Comment: mysqld  Ver 5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1 for debian-linux-gnu on i686 ((Ubuntu))

Comment: then it must be some prob wit the config i think !

Comment: You should get one more test case to make any decision - it may be my configuration that is bugged (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like just a different way for PHP to handle its memory.  It is much like using a dangling pointer in C++.

PHP Manual reads:

> Closes a prepared statement. mysqli_stmt_close() also deallocates the statement handle. If the current statement has pending or unread results, this function cancels them so that the next query can be executed.

You should always call "mysqli_stmt_close()" after you have retrieved all the results (or transfer the value to a different variable).

It sounds like Linux is writing over the memory location when it is freed, whereas Windows is keeping the old value until the memory is needed.

Comment: Then explain why LINUX eats all the unnecessary memory [as in this case], but WINDOWS eats memory only when it's hungry

Comment: Both are valid ways of memory management.  Also, it might not be the underlying operating system that is doing, but the PHP core.  Its not rare to implement different memory management for different operating systems.

Comment: Although it being different under different distributions of Linux would make it appear that it is the underlying operating system.  But, again, both are valid memory management techniques.

Comment: Different distributions of Linux may have different PHP versions installed by default as well. For example I have PHP 5.3.3, while @Sourav seems to have 5.2(5.6 in his post should be a mistake - 5.4 is only on alpha testing). It is interesting what his Windows PHP version is.

Comment: Thank Linux for showing you the error right away. If it was not that way, the script could crash randomly when memory is needed.